# Error embedding drupal views to twig template

Tags: theming

I'm getting an error `Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "drupal_view" function` when I try embedding my views to my twig template `{{ drupal_view('newsdesk', 'block_1') }}`.

I have already installed `twig_tweak`, `twig_extensions` and also installed `twig_extensions` via composer.

I'm not sure what else I'm missing, I've already also cleared the cache during installation

Answer (score 3):

That's an error you would get if the twig_tweak module is not enabled, are you sure you have enabled it? If you have multiple clones of your site, make sure you're on the right one.

Comment: Both modules are enabled/activated which is very confusing. No errors where displayed during the installation

Comment: @clestcruz uninstall both modules and then only enable `twig_teak`.